# Journey Builder | Is there an out of the box feature to send emails on the next day if it falls on a Canadian Statutory Holiday?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, holidays

Scenario:
Jane D. is a business owner with a business email address.
According to the business rules implemented in Journey Builder Jane D. is scheduled to receive email communications on Christmas Day.

Is there an out of the box feature in journey builder that:

1. Can identify the Statutory Holidays in Canada?
2. Can send the email on the next day if the email is scheduled to be deployed on the holiday?

Answer (score 3):

It would be pretty difficult to do it mid-journey, as you'd probably need to find a method of making a decision split based in multiple dates (a custom activity perhaps)

You could however do it if it's at the Journey Entry start. You would effectively store your public holidays dates in a data extension. Then using SQL to select your audience for the journey entry, you could join on `GetUTCDate` to only select an audience if it's not a public holiday.

Once they are in the journey, they would travel through the wait times and get your communications as you plan it out